# What species is this? Seashell from Indonesia

Tags: species-identification

[image: speshell]

Anyone know exactly what species this is?  I gather it may be an auger (family) or cerith (family) of some sort.

This particular one is native to Indonesia's black beaches.

I would like to know what is the genus and species of this specimen.

Answer (score 10):

That is a piece broken off of a sea urchin shell.

[image]

Without it's spines, it's not possible for me to say which species it is.

Comment: Good eye anongoodnurse +1

Comment: WOW!  Holy cow anongoodnurse, I am *impressed*.  You are totally right.